How to copy files in a docker images (reactjs build folder into node folder)
I have a question on how do I copy folder from one docker image to another.
I am working on a MERN STACK application, I have to two folders frontend(reactjs) server(nodejs). Each folder has its own Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml at the root level.
**React DOCKERFILE
**
FROM node:21.6.1 AS frontend

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

COPY . .

COPY build/ ../build

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

NODE DockerFILE

FROM node:21.6.1 AS server

RUN npm install -g nodemon

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]

docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo_c
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  api:
    build: ./server
    container_name: server_c
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - client
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb
  client:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: client_c
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
volumes:
  mongo-data: 


My Question is Here.. In my node application i am looking to copy my react.js build folder into node.js folder when creating a docker image so I can serve my react.js app on node port localhost:5000
in node app.js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});


I am looking for build folder from react.js, with this I am getting an error when trying to serve localhost:5000/profile (route in my react.js app) it give this error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'
I need help with so can i copy the build folder from react.js to node.js docker containers working directory /app to get this working.
I need a solution on how do I copy the react.js build folder into node folder to serve the react static app on node port
